How can I make a type safe nested object key getter?
I am trying to make a type safe getter function that you could give any object, and a . separated string key, and receive whatever value was in the object, maintaining the values type.
This is what I have at the moment:
function getObjectKeyTypeSafe<Type extends object>(obj: Type, key: string) {
  try {
    return key.split(".").reduce((previousObj, currentKey) => {
      type PreviousObjKeys = keyof typeof previousObj;

      return previousObj[currentKey as PreviousObjKeys];
    }, obj as any);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
}

For simplicity if anything goes wrong I intentionally am returning undefined.
I am new to typescript and I think the function is not type safe due to the type casting. I don't like that I am typecasting obj as any for the reduce's initial accumulator value. And I don't like that I am type casting currentKey as PreviousObjKeys when accessing the previousObj.
Example usage:
interface Test {
  first: string;
  last: string;
  data: {
    nested: string | number;
  }
}

let test: Test = {
  first: 'I am a string', 
  last: 'I am a string', 
  data: {
    nested: 6, 
  }
}

console.log(getObjectKeyTypeSafe<Test>(test, 'data.nested'));

The logged output is the correct type at the very least.
Potentially relevant docs?:
I was trying to implement the documented use case for "Generic Constraints" in the typescript docs on typescriptlang.org:
function getProperty<Type, Key extends keyof Type>(obj: Type, key: Key) {
  return obj[key];
}


You can't implement that with "type safety" inside the function, because the operations of splitting a string into path components and reduce-ing over it are way too complex to even represent in the type system, let alone verifying it as safe. But you can strongly type the call signature so that callers see what you intend, possibly as shown in this playground link. Keep in mind that such deeply nested types tend to have bizarre edge cases and are therefore fragile. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll post an a or find a duplicate; if not, what am I missing?

Yeah this is not easy, if not impossible. Here is a good answer on how to extract the nested keys of an object but there are many issues with it still. You could likely get the outside types correct to where your nested key aligns to the corresponding return type but the inside is hard. In these cases the best way is to force the types inside the function and write a lot of unit tests to validate the logic for every case, I did this for a recursive partial type.

@jcalz Yes I believe your comment answers the questions directly thank you. Your example in the TS playground does what I am hoping for as well and I will be going over it in detail to figure out how exactly it works. Thanks!

Please see linked q/a for more detailed information.
